# error in code of Guessing game java

Tags: java

okay, so this is suppose to be part of the full code, but the gist is, user guess the answer to a guessing number game and the moment user gets it right:

```
if (guess==num){
    System.out.println("You Win!");
    System.out.println("Play Again?? Y/N");

    String play=scan.nextLine();

    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        Game();
    }

    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        invalid(); //when playing again, it says you entered an invalid choice which i do not want.

        play=scan.nextLine();

        if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
            Game();
        }
    }
}
```

the output was:

.............................................

14

You Win!

Play Again?? Y/N

You entered an invalid choice, please re-enter Y/N       <<===== the problem is here
.................................................................

What i want is an input from the user in response to the play again?? question, but i do not understand what part of the code that caused me to print out you entered an invalid choice, can someone help? i just cant see the problem sadly. i still need the invalid method because i want to tell the user that when they enter an invalid answer to the y/n question.

Comment: Please don't delete the content of your question after someone has taken the time to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code can still enter the invalid section, after selecting yes. You need to use an **else if** statement

```
if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        Game();
}

else if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
    System.exit(1);
}

else{
   //...
}
```

Are you using a programming environment with debugging? With your original code, I recommend setting a breakpoint on the `System.out.println("You Win!");` line and then watch the pathway your code takes line by line. This will help you understand for yourself what's happening.

Even without debugging, you can add more `System.out` statements to get a better feel for the flow of your program.

```
String play=scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("My inputted value was " + play);

    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        System.out.println("Beginning new game...");
        Game();
    }

    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.out.println("Exiting game...");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    else{
```

Comment: im still a beginner coder and i haven't learnt about using breakpoint, but thanks for the tip, really!

Comment: after using your suggestion i found the problem! the code System.out.println("You Win!");
        System.out.println("Play Again?? Y/N");

        String play=scan.nextLine(); <<==== the string type scan did not start at all

Comment: @user1343502 Happy to help... but I hope you're not deleting this because you weren't allowed to ask for help and you want to hide this question from your teacher.

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        Game();
    }
```

Even if the user press Y, it is going to the next if/else

```
    if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.exit(1);
    } else {

        invalid(); //when playing again, it says you entered an invalid choice which i do not want.

            play=scan.nextLine();

            if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                Game();
            }
        }

    }
```

And since play is Y, it is calling the

```
invalid();
```

Comment: so the problem lies in the if condition?? somehow the String play=scan.nextLine(); isnt scanning any input and skips directly to the rest of the code?

Comment: The problem is actually you have two `if` statement. It will call both the `if` statement twice all the time. 
If the user press 'N', then it is fine because the first `if` is false. Now if the user press 'Y', it will enter the `else` statement in the second `if` which will be calling the `invalid();`.

Comment: i found the problem! the code System.out.println("You Win!"); System.out.println("Play Again?? Y/N"); String play=scan.nextLine(); <<==== the string type scan did not start at all